# condition in $hasMany or $belongsTo cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have three tables which are related through hasMany/belongsTo relationships.

```
user : name | type
page : name | content
page2: name | list


class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Page',
        'Page2'
    );

}
```

So the result now when the type fields = "page", the informations from page2 are also joined. I would liketo make it in that way . If the type = "page" then join only page model else if the typ = "page2" then join only page2.Is that possible ?

Comment: There is a _conditions_ capability built into the [$hasMany association](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany)

Comment: this condition is applied on the pages tables, When i write conditions => array("User.type" => "page") i got an error. Have you an example

Comment: is there any new ideas pls?